# How to append file in php with the id

Tags: php, session

When a user opens the page there is a count variable which increments by one. The count variable as well as the data are written in a file.

The problem concerns the session variable which is not incrementing. Every time the page loads there should be a increment in the session which should be put into the file.

The main idea is there is one textbox . A user just write the text apple Now the data is saving in the file along with the session variable which is counting. if the same user is again writing some thing in the textbox it will append the previous with the same session id

For example

**First time a user come And write in the textbox "I am a writer".**

```
session id      Text
24            I am a writer
```

**again the same user write in the textbox I am a chief. it should append with the same**

```
session id      Text
24           I am a writer I am a Chief
```

this is the php code

```
<?php
session_start();


if (isset($_SESSION["hello"]))
    $_SESSION["hello"]++;
else
    $_SESSION["hello"] = 1;

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $txt = "abc.txt";
    if (isset($_POST['field1'])) {
        $fh  = fopen($txt, 'a');
        $a   = $_SESSION["hello"];
        $txt = $a . '-' . $_POST['field1'];

        fwrite($fh, $txt . PHP_EOL);
        fclose($fh);

    }
}

echo $_SESSION["hello"];
```

HTML

```
<form action="index.php" method="POST">
    <input name="field1" type="text" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save Data">
</form>
```

Comment: Are you sure the counter is not incrementing? It works for me... Can you show what you get in the file "abc.txt"?

Answer (score 0):

I ran your code on a debian server and it seems to increment and save as expected. After writing something and submitting 3 times, abc.txt looks like this

```
cat abc.txt 
2-i'm the first entry! 
3-2nd line of input
4-3rd line!
```

Are you sure it's not a permission issue? If you're on Linux, try entering the directory containing index.php and doing the following.

```
sudo chmod +x index.php 
sudo chmod 777 .
```

Remember to change 777 to something more reasonable/less liberal once you've found the bug (777 grants full read/write/execute permission to anybody which is almost never the right choice in a production environment).
.